# What's the word to describe a person who acts like they don't make mistakes?

Tags: word-request

I thought of infallible , but it does not describe the person rather the behaviour. As in -- the person acts infallible.

Narcissist is a clinical term, and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Infallible does describe the person (consider the Pope), and 'the person acts infallible' is not grammatical.

Comment: Please mind that it should be "the person acts **infallibly**" instead of "infallible".

Comment: I think it should be 'acts as if infallible'. 'Acts infallibly' suggests that he actually **is** infallible. However, I think the OP wanted a word rather than a phrase.

Comment: To my Canadian ears, "*acts infallible*" is grammatical and means the same as "*acts as if he is infallible*" or more precisely, "*puts on an act which indicates he is infallible*".

Comment: Well, if you accept other adjectives like stupid or silly, then, you have to accept infallible, too.

Comment: It's not clear if you mean "I person who believes that they don't make mistakes (but actually makes mistakes".  Such a person would be arrogant.  Or do you mean a person who actually doesn't make mistakes, such a person would be infallible.  These are very different senses.

Comment: Infallible would mean the person doesn't make mistakes.  Very differnt from *acting as though* they don't make mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly 'arrogant'.

That describes more behaviours than simply not believing you are capable of mistakes, but it does encompass the required meaning.

'Know all' is close to what you require, but does not always imply that the person described won't admit errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such word to describe such person.  Supercilious or know-it-all come close. You can mock him or her as “ever- victorious general” in China， or “steady winner“ or ”who never fail“